# Add up several times and go over 24 hours

Tags: php, html, math

my problem is, that i am add over 5 times together with "h:s:m"
but i cant calculate the times. First there is a wrong calculate date and second the datetime don't go over 24 hours but i don't want to show dates only hours.

I tried already to calculate the times but every time there is a wrong result.

```php
          $worktime = 0;
          $worktimePause = 0;

          $UserID = $_POST['workerButtons'];
          $_SESSION['cur_user_id'] = $_POST['workerButtons'];
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM worktime WHERE `user_id` = '$UserID'";
          foreach ($mysql->query($sql) as $row) {
              $dif = gmdate("H:i:s",(strtotime($row["time_end"]) - strtotime($row["time_start"])));
              $worktime = gmdate("H:i:s", strtotime($worktime) + strtotime($dif)); #worktime should be the result in h:m:s for example 29:20:21

              echo "<tr><td>" . date('d.m.Y', strtotime($row["date"])). "</td><td>" . $row["time_start"] . "</td><td>". $row["time_end"]. "</td><td>" . $dif . "</td><td>". calculateHours($dif)."</td></tr>"; 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using PHP's [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes - they have a lot of date & time related functionality built-in. For example:

```
<?php
$clockInDatetime = new \DateTime('2019-06-07 13:59:03');/* Clocked in at 1:59:03 pm */
$clockOutDatetime = new \DateTime('2019-06-08 02:05:56');/* Clocked out at 2:05:56 am the following day */
$interval = $clockInDatetime->diff($clockOutDatetime);
?>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Clocked-in DateTime:</td>
            <td><?php echo $clockInDatetime->format('Y/m/d @ H:i:s a '); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Clocked-out DateTime:</td>
            <td><?php echo $clockOutDatetime->format('Y/m/d @ H:i:s a '); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Duration (H:i:s):</td>
            <td><?php echo $interval->format('%h:%i:%s'); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can even add multiple DateTimes/Intervals (consider lunchtime/breaks) like so:

```
<?php
$shiftInPre = new \DateTime('2019-06-07 13:59:03');/* Clocked in at 1:59:03 pm */
$shiftOutPre = new \DateTime('2019-06-07 18:30:25');/* Clocked out for lunch at 6:30:25 pm */
$shiftInPost = new \DateTime('2019-06-07 19:29:12');/* Clocked in from lunch at 7:30:12 pm */
$shiftOutPost = new \DateTime('2019-06-08 02:05:56');/* Clocked out at 2:05:56 am the following day */

/* Shift 1 duration */
$interval1 = $shiftInPre->diff($shiftOutPre);
/* Shift 2 duration */
$interval2 = $shiftInPost->diff($shiftOutPost);

/* Use new date to determine total duration of this days shifts */
$dateBase = new \DateTimeImmutable();
$dateSum = $dateBase->add($interval1);
$dateSum = $dateSum->add($interval2);
$shiftInterval = $dateBase->diff($dateSum);
?>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Shift 1:</td>
            <td><?php echo $interval1->format('%h:%i:%s'); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shift 2:</td>
            <td><?php echo $interval2->format('%h:%i:%s'); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td><?php echo $shiftInterval->format('%h:%i:%s'); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```